# How can I figure out why my Sears Craftsman garage door opener will not work?

Tags: electrical, garage-door-opener

I have tried troubleshooting my Craftsman door opener (model 139.53325SRT), because it will not close.

It will not close when pressing the wall switch: the opener light just blinks if I do that. Only the right side green light will glow, while the left sensor light will not come on.  Nothing has improved over two days of troubleshooting.

I have installed new door sensors.

Answer (score 2):

If both sensor lights are not on, the door opener will not close and the light will blink because the opener thinks there is something in the door path. This is a safety measure. One light being off is usually due to either the two sensors getting out of alignment, a faulty connection, or a faulty sensor.  You say that you have installed new door sensors.  If both lights are still not on, you have to troubleshoot that first. Check all connections and then try to align the 2 sensors. If both green lights are on, and the opener will still not open, then the fault is probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If the door sensors do not indicate that they are happy, it's expected that the door does not want to move. Did you replace the sensor wiring when you replaced the sensors? If not, suspect the wiring on the unhappy side. Presumably it's the receiver (the light source will show green if it's powered, the receiver will only show green if it "sees" the light source, indicating that the path is clear.) Check that the aiming of the sensors looks good and the lenses are not dirty or covered with some sort of protective plastic for shipping (since they are new.)

If the wiring all checks out as OK and the sensor still won't sense, it's time to suspect the control board in the opener. While replacements are usually available (and it's enlightening just how many "different brands" are actually all from the same company when you look for replacement parts) it's something of a gamble - I've done one, and it worked, but I was essentially betting about half the price of a new opener (with warranty) on a new board (no warranty) - in that case I had a pretty strong suspicion that it was lightning-strike damage, but it was a gamble.

I would certainly compare replacement parts and the terms they are sold under with replacing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a broken board, but its most like to be the sensor, or that the electronics are in a locked state due to obstruction.

Did you try to hold down the wired press button for a few seconds? I think that will bypass the previous obstruction state

To diagnose the sensor circuit, there are two ways:

- If you have a multimeter with continuity tester (tests for an open or closed circuit) you can test to see that the sensors are working. You would simply press the two test leads to make contact with the sensor wires, when un-obstructed I think the circuit should be normally closed, then when you obstruct, the sensor should open (ie no circuit) -- I could be wrong if its a normally open or closed setup though since im not certain.
- If you dont have a tester, you can just manually bypass the sensors whilst testing. you can do this by running a short piece of wire to each of the sensor board terminal screws (as shown in the diagram below) 
  [image]

Anyway, Thats what I would try. as, I said, I am not 100% certain of the specific details of this motor, and would appreciate somebody in the know to validate this answer... but for now, this may guide you...